# Relation between $f(x+y)$, $f(x)$ and $f(y)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$f(x)=x+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ then what is the relation between $f(x+y)$, $f(x)$ and $f(y)$

My Try: we have $$f(x+y)=x+y+\int_{0}^{x+y}f(t)dt$$ $\implies$

$$f(x+y)=x+y+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt+\int_{x}^{x+y}f(t)\,dt$$ $\implies$

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+y+\int_{x}^{x+y}f(t)\,dt$$ $\implies$

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+y+\int_{0}^{y}f(x+t)\,dt$$ Unable to proceed further.Help required

Answer (score 6):

Try to solve the equation first. Start by taking the derivative to turn it into a ODE:

$$f'(x) = 1 + f(x) \to \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)e^{-x}) = e^{-x}$$

which after integrating and using $f(0) = 0$ gives

$$f(x) = e^{x} - 1$$

Then its easy to see that

$$f(x+y) + 1 = (f(x) + 1)(f(y) + 1)$$

Comment: @AWertheim Yes, but showing that $f$ is differentiable is quite easy here. First show continutity and then use $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 1 + \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt$ to show differentiabillity.

Comment: Winther: indeed, I deleted my comment shortly after realizing that very fact. :) Nice solution, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Looks close to finish. I think it is just one step further to
$$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)+\int_0^y [f(x+t)-f(t)] \,dt$$
$$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)+\int_0^x [f(y+t)-f(t)] \,dt$$
I cannot see any simplification further.